# Is it possible to use Siri on html input fields in iOS?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, siri

I know I can add the following attribute to an input field and I get the speech capability in CHrome:

`x-webkit-speech="x-webkit-speech"`

However, does the capability exist to invoke Siri in iOS using a similar attribute?

Answer (score 0):

iOS7 is out and No API yet for Siri so the answer is NO